# Are the compilers in VisualStudio 2010 Express less optimized than their Professional version counterparts?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, visual-studio-express

I recall in the old days the Express version of the C++ portion of Visual Studio did not include the optimizing compiler. Is this the case? I would guess that it's less of an issue for the managed languages since the optimization occurs during JITting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they are not.  The **exact** same compilers ship in Express and Non-Express SKUs.